# Display a bottom menu

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How can display a menu in the bottom of the screen?
I have an UIImagePickerController and I want to let user select the source type. I want 3 buttons: "Take from photo library", "Take from camera", "Cancel".

Here is a screenshot of what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3JoQ.jpg

How can I do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are supporting iOS 8 and above, Use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`. And if you are supporting below that, use `UIActionSheet`. For more details on how to use `UIAlertController`, look at this [blog](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/).